# PHP write file... need help

Tags: php4

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$filename = $title , ".php";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die ("can't open file");
$stringData = $title;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $blog;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

This is only a sample. What is the correct code for that?

Comment: Correct code for what, exactly?  You need to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the correct code there, what is the point?

Also note that you are using a comma rather than a dot to concatenate strings at:

```
$filename = $title , ".php";
```

Comment: This is the error shows if i use that code.... I don't know why but it says that the comma has an error... "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Jordan Pagaduan\blog_creator.php on line 11"

Comment: @Jordan: as Sarfraz said in his answer, concatenation is done with a `.`, not a `,`.  Swap the `,` for a `.` and it should work.

Comment: oh.... thank you so much... i didn't understand the answer of sarfraz.. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

In your example opening a file using POST is an insecure method, so don't even think about this kinda tricks :P

You can use file read and write in simple method

[file_get_contents();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
echo $fileData = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
```

[file_put_contents();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$data= 'some data';
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents("filename.txt", $data);
```